# Performance partition postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have a table for which I need to use partitions to compute first, last, max, and min value over the partition.

The structure is the following:

```
select Table.*, 
        first_value("distance") over w,
        last_value("distance") over w, 
        min("distance") over w, 
        max("distance") over w
   from Table 
   window w as (partition by "path" order by "distance" rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following)
```

I noticed that the partition part is requiring a lot of time and was wondering if there was any way to speed up my query ?

I looked at the best practices https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITION-PRUNING but have not found something I can use in my case.

I am also wondering if there are maybe other more efficient way to compute the min/max per partitions.

Comment: "partition pruning" has nothing to do with the "partition by" clause of a window function.

Comment: Yes, well spotted thank you

Comment: You should share your create statement to see what indexes you have

Comment: I don't use any create statement. I am only selecting values from existing tables, that have not been created for my purpose.

Comment: Could you please share the results (in plain text) from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS) for this statement, and also the DDL for your tables and indexes involved?

Comment: I have used the explain command, but the output is rather large, I have 1000+ rows and there are more rows to fetch. What I wrote as Table is actually a bunch of others subqueries. Can I isolate those from the rest to have only what I need in the explain statement

Comment: Put the result at this site, https://explain.depesz.com ,  and share the link with us. And please share the entire plan, not half of it, without the actual problem....

Comment: Here is the link https://explain.depesz.com/s/1nlC